# How to install Ubuntu on non-UEFI?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bios

I have an assignment in which I have to give the steps of the installation.
So I request you to be very specific on the steps

Answer (score 0):

Legacy support should be enabled in BIOS. Go to boot options (machine specific method) and select the non UEFI Ubuntu entry to boot (after inserting installation media). If you see a pinkish screen, you have booted in BIOS mode. If you see grub boot loader in black background, means that you have booted in UEFI mode.